# DevExpress XtraReport shows empty DetailReport but correct rowcount

Tags: devexpress, report, visual-studio-lightswitch, xtrareport, lightswitch-2012

I'm using XtraReports 12.2.12 in my lightswitch project.
This projects connects to a sql database as datasource.

I created a report class and added a query as datasource for the report.
Then added a detailreport with the context menu -> "Insert detail report" to a bound list. (Suggested by xtrareports)

This bound report actually contains the data of a n to n mapping table with references to the corresponding tables. In the detailreport I try to display the data of one of these tables but receive only empty fields.

The funny thing is - the rowcount of empty rows (countable because of the labels I inserted into the report) is correct - only the data is missing.
I thought maybe the xtrareports component is not able to load the data from the referenced table but even the data from the detail report main table is not shown.

Maybe someone could give me a hint on how to solve this.

Thx in Advance

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem was to get rid of the unbound datasource in the report and put every subreport in a separate report class and then insert XRSubReport Control in the main report to include the newly created report, pass parameters and handle BeforePrint events correctly.